# Flutter Decorate Drop Down Button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a dropdown button, and im trying to decorate or customize the dropdown but only the list of items that is shown when trying to select the item in the list of items, i want the inside to look like this [image]

```
Center locationDropDown() {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 12,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue.shade50,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
          iconSize: 28,
          iconEnabledColor: Colors.blue,
          isDense: false,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please select a location';
            }
          },
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
            ),
          ),
          value: chooseLocation,
          hint: const Text(
            'Select your project',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.blue),
          ),
          isExpanded: true,
          items: workingData!.map((account) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(
                account.name + ' (${account.location})',
              ),
              value: account.id,
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (String? displayedValue) {
            setState(
              () {
                chooseLocation = displayedValue!;
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using [DropdownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2).

Also, For adding dividers with different height than other items, check out Example 3.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the package mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the side: property. By default it is BorderSide.none.

```
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        ),
      ),
```

Example;-

```
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        // Remove the debug banner
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Kindacode.com',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
        ),
        home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<String> _animals = ["Dog", "Cat", "Crocodile", "Dragon"];

  String? _selectedColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Kindacode.com'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedColor = value;
              });
            },
            value: _selectedColor,

            // Hide the default underline
            underline: Container(),
            hint: Center(
                child: Text(
              'Select the aniaml you love',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            )),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_downward,
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
            isExpanded: true,

            // The list of options
            items: _animals
                .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          e,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                      ),
                      value: e,
                    ))
                .toList(),

            // Customize the selected item
            selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => _animals
                .map((e) => Center(
                      child: Text(
                        e,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.amber,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but im talking about when the button is pressed and it shows the list of items, i posted a photo on the question